# How Often Do Windows Servers Need to be Restarted?

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server, restart

Our system team said that they recommended restarting all servers at least once a month. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/274089/how-often-do-windows-servers-need-to-be-restarted) old thread on serverfault and I wanted to learn your opinions. Should I restart SharePoint servers monthly or not? Any pros and cons?

Comment: I believe that IT also have a server restart for us, though I believe it is once a week.  I'm no expert on servers though, see what some others say about it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guidance on it but as per my experience, We never rebooted the server in regular intervals.  There are times when a reboot required.

- install a update for SharePoint or windows which required reboot
- install any add-on on the server which required reboot
- if there is an issue with Server which required reboot...memory usage out of control, Http throttling issue etc.

their is no hard rule, the reason why we dont do the reboot

- Our environment is 24/7 and there are services & 3rd party tool installed on the server which cause the outage.
- Sometime after reboot, our services take too much time to come back normal. i.e build cache will take time (depending the farm utilization).

again their is no hard and fast rule. reboot it if required or if you think it will not cause outage.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for opinion, i would say, atleast once in a wee just to keep systems in check.

But when you apply updates/Patches etc, which anyways comes monthly now a days mostly, you have to restart it anyways monthly. But just to keep systems in check i would recommend you to restart it weekly or alternate weeks atleast